# javascript to select form option

Tags: javascript, php, forms

```
<div id="pdf">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_pdf_file( elem ) {
            var filename = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
            var file_id = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].id;
            var id = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].index;
            // output some stuff to console: it works
            console.log( 'get_pdf_file( elem ) filename id: ' + id );
        }
    </script>
    <div id="choose_pdf">
        <form id="select_pdf_file">
            <select name="pdf_file" onChange="get_pdf_file( this )">
                <?php
                    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count_filenames; $i++ ) {
                        if ( $i == 0 ) {
                            echo '<option id="file_' . $i . '" value="' . $filenames[$i] . '" selected >' . $filenames[$i] . '</option>';
                            $pdf_file = $filenames[$i];
                        } else {
                    echo '<option id="file_' . $i . '" value="' . $filenames[$i] . '">' . $filenames[$i] . '</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    # output from above:
                    #<option id="file_1" value="tutorial_1.pdf" selected >tutorial_1.pdf</option>
                    #<option id="file_2" value="tutorial_2.pdf" >tutorial_2.pdf</option>
                    # ...
                    # ...
                ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- here is the container to output the selected file "$pdf_file" (see above)-->
    <object width="1000" height="803" type="application/pdf" data="<?php echo $pdf_file ?>?#zoom=58.7&scrollbar=1&toolbar=1&navpanes=1" id="pdf_content">
        <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
    </object>
</div>
```

The variable `$count_filenames` is the number of elements in an array named `$filenames` containing the names of various .pdf files...

Believe I miss some code as user action selecting tutorial_2.pdf for example always output the same file i.e. tutorial_1.pdf…

Please help solving this!

Answer (score 0):

you should do the same `$pdf_file = $filenames[$i];` in else condition too.

```
 else {
            echo '<option id="file_' . $i . '" value="' . $filenames[$i] . '">' . $filenames[$i] . '</option>';
$pdf_file = $filenames[$i];
        }
```

Comment: … testing for $i == 0 in the for loop is just to indicate that the first file in the array will be selected and then echoed in the object script of the page… My objective is to do all the stuff "without reloading the page therefore may be AJAX code is needed!

Answer (score 0):

Even better,

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count_filenames; $i++ ) {
    if ( $i == 0 ) 
        echo '<option id="file_' . $i . '" value="' . $filenames[$i] . '" selected >' . $filenames[$i] . '</option>';
    else 
        echo '<option id="file_' . $i . '" value="' . $filenames[$i] . '">' . $filenames[$i] . '</option>';
    $pdf_file = $filenames[$i];
}
```

Comment: … adding "$pdf_file = $filenames[$i];" to the else condition just don't work: I just want the "<object … data="<?php echo $pdf_file ?>? ...></object> to reflect user's choice to select an other option! And to do so I miss some extra code (AJAX, may be?)